# Passing object value as parameter to JS function using Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, radio-button

So I want to pass the object value "Policeman" as parameter in the function radioChange, but I cant find any ways to do it. Tried this.value trying to reference the html radio button but it doesnt work :(

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Profession, "Policeman", new { onchange="radioChange(object value)" })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind using jQuery?  If not replace the js with vanilla code. I just want to emphasize that the binding of the change event should be done in your js.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Profession, "Policeman", new { class="MyRadio" })
```

js:

```
$('.MyRadio').change(function(){
   radioChange($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: this is better form. But does it fix the actual problem OP is facing?

Comment: @DaveA I believe it does, he's having trouble extracting the value of the input

Comment: Yes he is. I would guess that as bad as inline JS practice is, it should behave no differently. We'll have to see when he tries it, but I would've guessed this is an encoding problem

Comment: Aaaah, i see, the post was edited. he wanted a handle to (this). Now I've flipped the other way. This may be all he needs.

Comment: I already knew this way but thanks anyway, my really question was if theres anyway to do this with the razor sintax.